# Maven WADL plugin for REST API spanning multiple project

Tags: java, rest, maven, wadl

I'm trying the `maven-wadl-plugin`. (I didn't find any documentation besides [the Javadoc](https://jar-download.com/java-documentation-javadoc.php?a=maven-wadl-plugin&g=com.sun.jersey.contribs&v=1.19.3).)

My project has the classes used for REST endpoints amongst different Maven modules. And the WADL plugin seems not to be able to reach for them. So running on a single module fails with:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal 
   com.sun.jersey.contribs:maven-wadl-plugin:1.19.4:generate (generate) 
on project bpds-resources: Execution generate of goal com.sun.jersey.contribs:maven-wadl-plugin:1.19.4:generate 
failed: A required class was missing while executing 
  com.sun.jersey.contribs:maven-wadl-plugin:1.19.4:generate: com/.../common/dto/BoxRequestDto
```

The plugin doesn't support running from the root project either.

1) AFAIK, `maven-wadl-plugin` parses the sources. My project results in a one big shaded `.jar` so the plugin could consume that and not care about the internal dependencies. Can I make the plugin scan the artifact instead?

2) Is there a way to make it work over multiple projects?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that adding the project dependency to the scanned module works. So I have added the attribute with the DTO classes and now it works:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-wadl-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.4</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
                    <version>2.25.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.10</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
                    <version>2.25.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.mycompany.bpds</groupId>
                    <artifactId>bpds-common</artifactId>
                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>

                    <configuration>
                        <wadlFile>${project.build.directory}/endpoints.wadl</wadlFile>
                        <formatWadlFile>true</formatWadlFile>
                        <baseUri>http://localhost:9021/</baseUri>
                        <packagesResourceConfig>
                            <param>com.mycompany.rest</param>
                        </packagesResourceConfig>
                        <wadlGenerators>
                            <!-- Doesn't work wit current version of Xerces.
                            <wadlGeneratorDescription>
                                <className>com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.generators.WadlGeneratorApplicationDoc</className>
                                <properties>
                                    <property>
                                        <name>applicationDocsFile</name>
                                        <value>${project.build.directory}/app-wadl-doc.xml</value>
                                    </property>
                                </properties>
                            </wadlGeneratorDescription>
                            <wadlGeneratorDescription>
                                <className>com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.generators.WadlGeneratorGrammarsSupport</className>
                                <properties>
                                    <property>
                                        <name>grammarsFile</name>
                                        <value>${project.build.directory}/app-wadl-grammar.xml</value>
                                    </property>
                                </properties>
                            </wadlGeneratorDescription>
                            -->
                        </wadlGenerators>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```